# How to dissassemble a MOVEM instruction in 68k using the register list mask field?

Tags: 68000

Example Problem:

> Refer the manual (pp. 232) for MOVEM instruction. Disassemble the
> following instruction.
>
> 4CDF 0F24

Binary:
0100 1100 1101 1111 0000 1111 0010 0100

10th bit is 1 so memory to register

6th bit is 1 so long transfer

Effective Address: 011 111 --> (An)+

Therefore, we can assume

MOVEM.L (Sp)+, _____

This is where I get stuck.

I'm not quite sure how to convert 0F24. The answer states that the registers being moved are
A0/A1/A2/A3/D2/D5, but how do you get this answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 16 bits and each bit corresponds to one of the 16 registers `D0-D7/A0-A7`. The order of the bits depends on the address mode. Usually, and in your case:

```
0000 1111 0010 0100
^... ...^ ^... ...^
`-A7    | `-D7    `-D0
        `-A0
```

In pre-decrement mode, the bitorder would be reversed.